# Operator overloading with function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

My job is to overload `operator<<` so it can print any object (e.g `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::deque`, etc.)

With my basic knowledge of templates and searching the web I came out with something like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<T>& v){
    stream << '[';
    for(const auto& element : v){
        stream << element << ' ';
    }
    stream << ']';
    
    return stream;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<double> foo = {1.2, 2.1, 3.56};
    std::set<double> roo = {1.2, 2.1, 3.56};
    
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << roo << std::endl;
}
```

But it won't print `std::set` or any other object. I've tried replacing `const std::vector<T>& v` with `const T& v` but it won't compile. Any tips on how can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried replacing `const std::vector<T>& v` with `const T& v` but it won't compile.

You can put constraints on the type to avoid conflict with overloaded `operator<<` provided by the library. E.g.

```
// works on types supporting std::begin and std::end
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const T& v) -> decltype(std::begin(v), std::end(v), stream) {
    stream << '[';
    for(const auto& element : v){
        stream << element << ' ';
    }
    stream << ']';
    
    return stream;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DdfSyFj7KD6M3Y51)